# How to display links from an array of objects separately on a new line?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, amcharts, amcharts4

In my JavaScript array of objects, I have a problem displaying multiple links from the objects corresponding to each country on a separate line for each of them.

The current loop takes all the links corresponding to the countries and displays the name of country.

The problem with links is that if a country has multiple links, I can't have them displayed separately.

For example, those three DE links are displayed in tooltip as one single link:
`https%3A%2F%2Fwwww.example1.com%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwwww.example2.com%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwwww.example3.com` and I want each link on a separate line.

How can I write the loop better in order to achieve what I want?

The loop currently looks like this:

```
//Loop for displaying links corresponding to each country
        group.data.forEach(function(link){
            let polygonTemplate = series.mapPolygons.template;
        // Instead of our custom country, we could also use {name} which comes from geodata  
          polygonTemplate.tooltipHTML = '<b>{country}</b><br><a href="{link.urlEncode()}">More info</a>';
          polygonTemplate.fill = am4core.color("blue");
        });
```

You can check also the JSFiddle snippet to see more clearly what I mean.

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Thank you!

```js
am4core.ready(function() {

    // Themes begin
    am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
    // Themes end
    
    // Create map instance
    let chart = am4core.create("map", am4maps.MapChart);
    
    // Set map definition
    chart.geodata = am4geodata_worldHigh;
    
    // Set projection
    chart.projection = new am4maps.projections.Mercator();
    
    // Zoom control
    chart.zoomControl = new am4maps.ZoomControl();
    
    let homeButton = new am4core.Button();
    homeButton.events.on("hit", function() {
      chart.goHome();
    });
    
    homeButton.icon = new am4core.Sprite();
    homeButton.padding(7, 5, 7, 5);
    homeButton.width = 30;
    homeButton.icon.path = "M16,8 L14,8 L14,16 L10,16 L10,10 L6,10 L6,16 L2,16 L2,8 L0,8 L8,0 L16,8 Z M16,8";
    homeButton.marginBottom = 10;
    homeButton.parent = chart.zoomControl;
    homeButton.insertBefore(chart.zoomControl.plusButton);
    
    // Center on the groups by default
    chart.homeZoomLevel = 5;
    chart.homeGeoPoint = { longitude: 10, latitude: 52 };
    
    let groupData = [
      {
        "color": chart.colors.getIndex(0),
        "data": [
          {
            "country": "Germany",
            "id": "DE", // With MapPolygonSeries.useGeodata = true, it will try and match this id, then apply the other properties as custom data
            "link": ["https://wwww.example1.com", "https://wwww.example2.com", "https://wwww.example3.com"],
          }, {
            "country": "France",
            "id": "FR",
            "link": ["https://wwww.example4.com"],
          }, {
            "country": "Belgium",
            "id": "BE",
            "link": ["https://wwww.example5.com", "https://wwww.example6.com"]
            
          },
            {
            "country": "Netherlands",
            "id": "NL",
            "link": ["https://wwww.example7.com"]
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
    
    // This array will be populated with country IDs to exclude from the world series
    let excludedCountries = ["AQ"];
    
    // Create a series for each group, and populate the above array
    groupData.forEach(function(group) {
      let series = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
      series.name = group.name;
      series.useGeodata = true;
      let includedCountries = [];
      // Make a loop to display a link for the group of countries
      group.data.forEach(function(country) {
        includedCountries.push(country.id);
        excludedCountries.push(country.id);
        
                //Loop for displaying links corresponding to each country
    group.data.forEach(function(link){
        let polygonTemplate = series.mapPolygons.template;
    // Instead of our custom country, we could also use {name} which comes from geodata  
      //polygonTemplate.tooltipHTML = '<b>{country}</b><br><a href="{link.urlEncode()}">More info</a>';
      polygonTemplate.tooltipHTML = '<b>{country}</b>' + link.link.map(url =>
  '<br><a href="{url.urlEncode()}">More info</a>').join("");
      polygonTemplate.fill = am4core.color("blue");
    });
        
      });
      series.include = includedCountries;
    
      series.fill = am4core.color(group.color);
      series.setStateOnChildren = true;
      series.calculateVisualCenter = true;
      series.tooltip.label.interactionsEnabled = true;
            series.tooltip.keepTargetHover = true;
    

      // Country shape properties & behaviors
      let mapPolygonTemplate = series.mapPolygons.template;
      mapPolygonTemplate.fill = am4core.color(group.color);
      mapPolygonTemplate.fillOpacity = 0.8;
      mapPolygonTemplate.nonScalingStroke = true;
      mapPolygonTemplate.tooltipPosition = "fixed";
            
    
      mapPolygonTemplate.events.on("over", function(event) {
        series.mapPolygons.each(function(mapPolygon) {
          mapPolygon.isHover = false;
        })
        event.target.isHover = false;
        event.target.isHover = true;
      })
    
      mapPolygonTemplate.events.on("out", function(event) {
        series.mapPolygons.each(function(mapPolygon) {
          mapPolygon.isHover = false;
        })
        
      })
    
      // States  
      let hoverState = mapPolygonTemplate.states.create("hover");
      hoverState.properties.fill = am4core.color("#9985e3");
    
      series.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(group.data));
      
    });
    
    // The rest of the world.
    let worldSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
    let worldSeriesName = "world";
    worldSeries.name = worldSeriesName;
    worldSeries.useGeodata = true;
    worldSeries.exclude = excludedCountries;
    worldSeries.fillOpacity = 0.5;
    worldSeries.hiddenInLegend = true;
    worldSeries.mapPolygons.template.nonScalingStroke = true;


});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
  }
  #map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
  }
  a {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: rgb(4, 7, 46);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Some countries</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css">
</head>
<!-- Scripts for loading AmCharts Map -->
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/maps.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/geodata/worldHigh.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand how `link.urlEncode()` is working. `link` is an object with `country`, `id`, and `link` properties, it doesn't have a `urlEncode()` method.

Comment: @Barmar Here you can find more information about those clickable links: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/clickable-links-in-tooltips/

Comment: I recommend you be consistent in making the `link` property always an array, even if it's just a single URL. Otherwise you need to add a conditional to check if it's an array that needs looping.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: @Barmar I edited the code based on your suggestion with some modifications to display properly the encoded links in tooltip and added an answer to this question.

The only problem remaining is that both countries are displaying the same links from the last country available in the array of objects.

How can I make the countries to display only the links belonging to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `map()` to iterate over the `link` property and make each URL a separate line in the `tooltipHTML` property.

```
polygonTemplate.tooltipHTML = '<b>{country.country}</b>' + country.link.map(url =>
  '<br><a href="{url.urlEncode()}">More info</a>').join("");
```

Comment: It's defined in `group.data.forEach(function(link) ...)`

Comment: You renamed `link` to `country` in your edit after I started writing the answer.

Comment: Don't change the question to incorporate the answer. Readers need to see the original code to see what I changed.

Comment: Are you still seeing the same incorrect output with my change? I find that difficult to believe.

Comment: I tried your @Barmar code and now country is not appearing in tooltip. Even href property does not contain link. I think we need to add tooltipHTML every time showToolTip() function  is getting called.

Comment: No Console is fine.

Comment: I don't see a `showToolTip()` function in the code.

Comment: But you're right, this code just runs one time when the `ready` event occurs. If you need it to change dynamically, it should be in some other event.

Comment: Its a event binded to mapPolygonTemplate object. Unminify map.js and see line no. 3413 and for core.js 33953. You can watch tooltipHTML there.

Comment: @JustMe you can find your solution in mapPolygonTemplate.events.on("over", function(event) {.........  . Every time you hover over polygon this function is getting called. So if you will try to set tooltipHTML here for that event target, it may work.

Comment: I think I understand what the problem is, but not how to solve it. It has to do with the way the templating code works in amcharts. It can't reference local variables in the loop, it's referencing chart data.

Comment: We may find help referring to this docs : https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/mapchart/#Methods.

Comment: I edited the code based on the suggestion of @Barmar with some modifications to display properly the encoded links in tooltip.

`polygonTemplate.tooltipHTML = '<b>{country}</b>' + country.link.map(url =>
  '<br><a href="' + encodeURI(url) + '">Country links ' + '</a>').join("");`

Answer (score 0):

```
mapPolygonTemplate.events.on("over", function(event) {
        series.mapPolygons.each(function(mapPolygon) {
          mapPolygon.isHover = false;
        })
        event.target.isHover = false;
      group.data.forEach(function(country) {
          event.target.tooltipHTML = '<b>{country}</b>' + country.link.map(url =>
  '<br><a href="{link.urlEncode()}">More info</a>').join("");
          polygonTemplate.fill = am4core.color("blue");
});
        event.target.isHover = true;
      });
```

This is how its solution will look like. I haven't tried this on fiddle but I am pretty sure about the flow. Look if you can set toolTipHtml when setToolTip() is getting called.

One more thing if you can associate the hovered polygon with your JSON data then you don't need to loop over "**group.data**", but fetch the object from the array and append the link into toolTipHtml.